# codeigniter upload not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

i have a problem. I'm using CodeIgniter on Xampp Lite and the upload form doesn't work, it returns

> You did not select a file to upload.

I declared the form multipart, the input's name is userfile, i set all upload-related vars on, but it doesn't works.

Here's the part of source code:

Controller

```
 public function send($id,$doupload=false)  {
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url', 'html'));
        $config = 
 array(

                'upload_path'     => dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/files/",
                   'upload_url'      => base_url()."files/",
                   'allowed_types'   => "cpp",
                   'overwrite'       => TRUE,
                   'max_size'        => "1000KB", 
                 );         
$this->load->library('upload',$config);         $data=array(            'page_title'=>lang('send_source'),
            'form_sursa'=>array(
                 'name' => 'userfile',
                'id'    => 'sursa',
                 'size' => 20,          ), 
            'id'    => $id      );      
if ($doupload===false)      {
            $this->template->build('problems/send',$data);      }       else        {           if
 ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())            {
                echo ($data['upload_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->template->build('problems/send',$data);          }           else            {
                $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                $this->template->build('problems/send',$data);          }       }   }
```

The form part of template:

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart(site_url('probleme/trimite').$id./trimite',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));

 ?>     
<fieldset>      
<div class="control-group">
 <?php echo form_label(lang('sursa'), 'sursa', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
    <div class="controls"><?php echo form_upload($form_sursa); ?
><br
 />*<i><?php echo lang('sursa_upload_tip1'); ?></i></div>

                    </div> 
<div class="span7 offset2">
                     <div class="span2" style="text-align: center;">
                         <?php echo form_submit(array('name'  => 'submit', 'value' => 
lang('upload_source'), 'class' => 'btn')); ?>
                     </div>


 <div class="clearfix hspace"></div>
         </div>     
</fieldset>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    # rewrite `pub/` requests
    #   IE: [app_path]/themes/default/css/ maps to [app_path]/pub/themes/default/css/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?:themes|upload)\b.* pub/$0 [L]

    # this adds trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

    # Secure directories
    RewriteRule ^(app|core) index.php [R=404,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|pub|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|humans\.txt\|sitemap\.gz|sitemap\.xml)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # Prevent directory listings
    Options -Indexes

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    #
    #   -> Remember to add the subdirectory if necessary.
    #
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you dumped $_FILES to see if it has the file?

Comment: `VAR_DUMP()` your `$_FILES` array to make sure that the file is actually being sent to your controller.

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter? CI 2.1.1 fixed a bug with this symptom due to incorrect mime-type detection. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html

Comment: i already checked, $_FILES is empty - it shows Array()

Comment: i have the last version

Comment: please turn on your profiler and see on bottom of page what is sent ;) from where etc., `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`

Comment: i have it on, i have ci on developer mode...i discovered the problem...i was redirecting by .htaccess and the data was lost...my question is: how can i keep the redirect and make upload work?I posted my .htaccess

Comment: in your view i didn't see the `userfile` field

Comment: SOLVED...just added site_url('index.php/problems/etc') ONLY to the upload url

Comment: is echo form_upload($form_sursa) and if you look at the controller you will see that the name is userfile

Answer (score 1):

i hope this code is usefull to you

```
 <from .....>
      <input type="file" name='xyz'  />
 </form>
```

put your your file name in do_upload() function like...

```
  $this->upload->do_upload('xyz');
```

may be help you.....

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```